# Maximized Window with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my window to be maximized, like I pressed the button left to the X. Not Fullscreen.
I find that this can be with `root.state('zoomed')`. At the start it looks like its working, but it's not. The window sometimes appears maximized but when I click on it, it goes fullscreen.

I just want the taskbar on Windows to be shown and the Tkinter window to be maximized.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('')
root.state('zoomed')
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As I know, the "full screen"(without taskbar) can be achieved by `window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)`, by default, the taskbar will be shown in default. Could you provide some your code snippets?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it doesn't work because of `root.resizable(0,0)`. After deleting this line it works.

Comment: Yeah, I did the test, I am glad that you have figured it out.